# Postgres Selecting Records That Inserted within 2 hours apart

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on this Query and trying to select all records that are inserted within x hours apart

For example i have the following record

```
A      2018-04-11 18:00:00
B      2018-04-11 19:00:00
C      2018-04-11 20:00:00
D      2018-04-11 21:00:00
```

When the query is executed the time is 21:15:00, the query should take records that are occurred within the last 2 hours from the query is executed. So in this case it should return:

21:00:00 and 20:00:00

This is the query i am working on and it is not working as expected, because it only shows 2 records even if there are more than 2.

```
SELECT *
    FROM posts p1
    WHERE p1.created_at >= '2018-04-11 16:00:00'
    AND exists
    (
        SELECT p2.id
        FROM posts p2
        WHERE p2.created_at <= '2018-04-11 17:00:00'
        AND p2.created_at > p1.created_at
        AND p2.created_at - p1.created_at < INTERVAL '1 HOUR'
        AND p2.category_id = p1.category_id
        AND p2.city_id = p1.city_id
        AND p2.district_id = p1.district_id
        AND p2.subcategory_id = p1.subcategory_id
    )
    AND p1.category_id = 3;
```

*EDIT*

Apologize for not being clear with my question, the reason why my query above is complex because i am trying to "cluster" my record. Basically i am trying to get records of the same category, that is posted in the same location (same cityID) that is posted by different users within the 2 hours time frame.

So when the query is executed at 21:00, it should return record that comes from the same location, posted on the same category, that are posted "roughly" at the same time. When i say "roughly" it is basically trying to get post that are posted within the last 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the query is executed the time is 21:15:00, the query should take records that are occurred within the last 2 hours from the query is executed.

Your query seems much too complicated.

Perhaps I'm confused by why wouldn't you just use this?

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.created_at >= current_timestamp - interval '2 hour';
```

If you are going to put your own values in, then you probably need:

```
select p.*
from posts p
where p.created_at >= '2018-04-11 16:00:00'::timestamp - interval '2 hour' and
      p.created_at < '2018-04-11 16:00:00'::timestamp;
```

I assume that posts cannot be created in the future.  That is not true if you are plugging in the current time.

Comment: Thanks for helping Gordon, but your query returns this error: [22007] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type interval: "2018-04-11 16:00:00" Position: 47

Comment: @Jeremy Where is `2018-04-11 16:00:00` coming from? It's not a valid interval value. Maybe you meant to replace `current_timestamp` with that value?

Comment: @Gordon, i am replacing current_timestamp with a value that i type myself for debugging / testing purposes.

Comment: Hi @Gordon i managed to get rid of the Error with invalid input syntax. However it returns data that is not as expected.

Comment: @Jeremy I would help if you update the question with new SQL and output you get

Comment: Hi @Gordon, thanks for helping and editing your query, but perhaps i am not clear with my question. Please see my edit.

Comment: hi @igr yep, i just updated my question. Please see my Edit